# How to wrap exceptions to provide context?

Tags: haskell

Say I have a function that downloads a file and tries to parse it. Regardless of what exception is raised by any low level functions used, I would like to enrich it with the context information by adding the url.

Comment: If you use parsec, it lets you input the source as a string, and will display that upon exception.

Comment: There is very little information in your question that makes it possible to answer.  Can you edit your question with a small example of what you're currently doing and a fuller description of what you'd like to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [possible to catch all exceptions, though not recommended](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception.html#g:4). You can then tag the exception with the URL and reraise it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}                                                                         
module Temp where                                                                                           

import Control.Exception                                                                                    
import Data.Typeable                                                                                        

type URL = String                                                                                           
data URLTaggedException e = URLTaggedException { baseException :: e, url :: URL } deriving (Typeable, Show) 
instance (Typeable e, Show e) => Exception (URLTaggedException e)                                           

tagExceptionsWithURL :: URL -> IO a -> IO a                                                                 
tagExceptionsWithURL url io = catch io (throwIO . tag)                                                      
  where tag :: SomeException -> URLTaggedException SomeException                                            
        tag e = URLTaggedException e url
```